# statement blocks Mechanism in Shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh

In **Beginning Linux Programming** book. There is a secition about **Statement Block**. In that Portion the explanation looks like the following.

## Statement Blocks

If you want to use multiple statements in a place where only one is allowed, such as in an AND or OR list,
you can do so by enclosing them in braces {} to make a statement block. For example, see the following code:

```
get_confirm && {
    grep −v "$cdcatnum" $tracks_file > $temp_file 
    cat $temp_file > $tracks_file
    echo
    add_record_tracks
}
```

***Please explain how the code is executing in the statement block...***

Comment: The code within the braces is executed the same way as if there were no braces.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The code within `{ ... }` execute exactly the way it would have executed without the curly braces, except now it's dependent on the exit status of `get_confirm`.

If `get_confirm` exits with a zero exit status ("success"), the block executes, otherwise not.

It's nearly equivalent to

```
if get_confirm; then
    # the contents of the block goes here
fi
```

(which I think looks nicer). "Nearly" because there's a difference in what result status is reported by each statement if `get_confirm` returns *false* (the short-circuit code will sett `$?` to non-zero, while the `if` statement will set the same variable to zero), and this may matter depending on the options set in the shell and what the surrounding code does.

The book's example is IMHO not a good example of a common use of `{ ... }`. A better example would have been

```
{ echo 'hello world'; date; } >file
```

which uses a single redirection to redirect the standard output of both commands in the `{ ... }` block to the same file.

This is similar to (and has the same effect, in this instance, as)

```
( echo 'hello world'; date ) >file
```

but the statements within `{ ... }` executes in the same environment as the shell, whereas the statements in `( ... )` executes in a subshell (a separate environment).

You can see the difference with

```
{ a=42; }; echo $a
```

and

```
( a=1973 ); echo $a
```

The first will output `42` whereas the second will not output `1973` (the assignment happens in a subshell and it can't affect the environment outside).

Notice about grammar: The closing `}` of a `{ ... }` block must follow a newline or a `;`.  `{ echo 'hello' }` is not valid, while both `{ echo 'hello'; }` and

```
{ 
    echo 'hello'
}
```

are.

Comment: @Kusalananda, sorry if it's offtopic but is this `{}` syntax - bash specific, or is it POSIX-compliant?

Comment: @DanM. The `{ ...; }` syntax is POSIX. It creates a compound command out of the commands that it encapsulates, so that "it acts as a single command" in terms of redirections etc.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks. I'll look into other causes that may explain why my script has an empty output under dash but not zsh and bash.

Comment: @DanM. You could ask a question about it.